# Identifying a couple more fonts

Tags: fonts, typography, logo, font-identification, typefaces

These two fonts are a pain to identify because of the formatting (one is partially masked) and the other is on a background that makes it hard to identify. There are two different images for the 2nd logo (cobaty)

[image: AFMC Logo]

[image: cobaty v1]

[image: cobaty v2]

Any idea what these fonts are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are
[Helvetica Black](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/helvetica/) (not Neue) and
[ITC Avant Garde Gothic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/itc/avant-garde-gothic/) using stylistic set 02 (modifies *ty*) + stylistic set 03 (modifies *c*). Additionaly, *c* looks being adjusted manually.

Comment: what do you mean when you say "stylistic set 02" and "stylistic set 03"?

Comment: ITC Avant Garde Gothic (Std and Pro versions) come with plenty of stylistic alternates. Some programs (like InDesign) allow switching them on and off not just with one button `Stylistic Alternates` but in separate `Stylistic Sets` - Avant Garde Gothic has 5 of them.